# JSF managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, javabeans, backing-beans

Hy all,

i am new with all of this,and probably this would be a dumb question,but

i have an managed bean that has a property flower - String, and a property List - bouquet

in a xhtml i have an h:inputText in witch you should type a flower name and when you click a h:command button it callas an action #{managedBEan.addFlower}, in addFlower i want to add the flower name typed by the user and added in list  --- i am using a h:form

but it seems that the set method for property aren't called by jsf when i click the button, the flower property have null as value, like she was declared

thank you for your sugestions,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Bean:

```
... myBean() {
   Flower flower;

   (...)

   public void addFlower() { }

   //getters and setters for Flower prop.
}
```

Xhtml

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.flower.name}"/>
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.addFlower}" value="Click me!"/>
```

Thats all you have to do. A instance for flower with get and set and a `h:inputText` with the flower name in "value" property.

When you clicks the button, the value typed will be put in the property referenced in value, so if you print the `flower.name` (in addFlower method) you will be able to see the user input.

`actionListener` works too, but you need to check wich import you are using for `ActionEvent`. IDE always import `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` but the right one is `javax.faces.event.ActionEvent`... `java.awt` doesn't work and I guess thats why your method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an **actionListener**, like this:

```
<h:commandButton actionListener="#{myBean.addFlower}" . . .
```

and in your bean you must define addFlower

```
   public void addFlower(ActionEvent ev)
```

that execute the job.

Comment: i defined it , and the method is called, i checked

Comment: the setMethod for properties are not called

Answer (score 0):

Does an  tag surround both, the input and the button?

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.flower.name}"/>
    <h:commandButton action="#{myBean.addFlower}" value="Click me!"/>
</h:form>
```

Otherwise the input will not be sent.